# In angular2 I deployed my app to firebase hosting and on refresh of the pages I get 404 error

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase

In angular2 I deployed my app to firebase hosting and on refresh of the pages I get 404 error.

The route works fine when you click on the website but when you click refresh the page disappears.

**This is my firebase.json:**

```
{
  "firebase": "************",
  "public": "prod",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {"source": "**", "destination": "/index.html"}
  ]
}
```

Or do I need some angular2 code to cater for this?

Comment: Looks correct (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206362/angularjs-html5mode). What is the exact error message?

Comment: I dont get an error but when my site is live it doesnt refresh back to that index

Comment: Whats the correct folder structure for the app deploy and where should the firebase.json file sit?

Comment: No idea. I just remembered seeing that question already and googled.

Comment: You wrote in your question you get a 404. That usually comes with a full error message.

Comment: I get a firebase 404 error

Comment: Click this link : https://poolcover-dev.firebaseapp.com/ and then navigate and then refresh browser

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer any ideas?