# Application always serves '/' to express app

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, express, angular-universal

Have an angular 7 application and have implemented angular universal using node and express, and then deployed to firebase.

Having an issue when trying to load pages other than the root (/), which causes the server to return the html of the root (/) rather than the page the user requests.

Not sure from where the issue is originating (Angular, Angular Universal or Firebase).

This is my `index.ts`:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import {renderModuleFactory} from '@angular/platform-server';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import {readFileSync} from 'fs';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

const indexHtml = readFileSync(__dirname + '/index-server.html', 'utf-8').toString();

const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./main');

import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  // Always '/' (root path)
  console.log('OPTIONS.REQ.URL', options.req.url);

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // My index-server.html
    document: indexHtml,
    url: options.req.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('*.*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist', {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(__dirname + '/index-server.html', {req});
});

exports.ssrApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HomePageComponent} from './home-page/home-page.component';
import {ToursComponent} from './tours/tours.component';
import {MaltaComponent} from './malta/malta.component';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {ContactComponent} from './contact/contact.component';
import {TourComponent} from './tours/tour/tour.component';
import {ErrorComponent} from './error/error.component';
import {BlogComponent} from './blog/blog.component';
import {BlogPageComponent} from './blog/blog-page/blog-page.component';
import {PageResolver} from './services/pages/page-resolver.service';

const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomePageComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'home',
      pageId: 'home'
    },
    resolve: {
      page: PageResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'tours',
    component: ToursComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'tours',
      pageId: 'tours'
    },
    resolve: {
      page: PageResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'tours/:id',
    component: TourComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'tour'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'blog',
    component: BlogComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'blogs',
      pageId: 'blog'
    },
    resolve: {
      page: PageResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'blog/:id',
    component: BlogPageComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'blog'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'malta',
    component: MaltaComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'malta',
      pageId: 'malta'
    },
    resolve: {
      page: PageResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'about',
      pageId: 'about'
    },
    resolve: {
      page: PageResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'contact',
      pageId: 'contact'
    },
    resolve: {
      page: PageResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'something-went-wrong',
    component: ErrorComponent,
    data: {
      state: 'error',
      pageId: 'error'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/something-went-wrong'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {
      useHash: true,
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      initialNavigation: 'enabled'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

This is my `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrApp"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  }
}
```

Would appreciate any help with this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved after removing `useHash: true` from the `app-routing.module.ts`.

Thanks to **yeya** for helping get to the solution.

Comment: Mark it as the correct answer. so your question won't left in 'unanswered' list

Comment: Once Stackoverflow allows me to mark it correct I will :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to [Browser URL styles](https://angular.io/guide/router#browser-url-styles)

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25342244/3107689): Try change the rewrites from `"function": "ssrApp"` to `"destination": "/index-server.html"`

The request`index-server.html` will trigger the function.

Comment: Hi yeya, thanks for your answer. I changed the rewrites like you said however now I am getting a 404 error. Is the firebase.json file the only change I need to make?

Comment: Please read and try to understand the links I provided. It can help you much better than my answer.

Comment: Thanks yeya, it was the `useHash: true` that caused the behaviour. Appreciate the help!